# Find resistor values for potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

[image]

I'm supposed to find R1 and R2 so that the potentiometer outputs -1 to 1 V. I've been trying for hours so I'm ready to throw in the towel. I know the voltage across R1 and R2 have to be 1 V and -1 V respectively, but I just can't figure out how to obtain those values. Any help would be much appreciated. Feel free to ignore the stuff regarding R3 and R4, that's something I could do just fine.

Comment: I think the voltages across R1 and R2 should be 14 volts, not 1 volt.  You can claculate the current through the potentiometer, so a bit of Ohm's Law work should give you the values for R1 and R2.

Comment: @PeterBennett My god, I need to take a break. You were absolutely right. That was it! Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake

Comment: Vin indicates -1 to 2V not -1 to 1V so 3V across 10k implies 0.3mA total and you figure out the rest.

Comment: @Max Feel free to post your answer. Doesn't have to be long. Just a correct answer. It helps to put the question to bed. :)  You can even select it, though you may want to wait for comments to trickle in, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The two things to know about resistive potential dividers are:

1. Each resistor will develop a voltage across it in proportion to its resistance.
2. The sum of all the voltages across each resistor is equal to the total voltage \$V_T\$.

If you consider an individual resistor \$R_X\$ in a chain of N resistors, as being a fraction of the total resistance \$R_T\$, these principles can be combined into an algebraic expression as follows, where \$V_{RX}\$ is the voltage across \$R_X\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{RX} = V_T\frac{R_X}{R_1+R_2+\cdots +R_N} = V_T\frac{R_X}{R_T}
\end{aligned}
$$

It's important to realise that here \$V_{RX}\$ is not an absolute potential anywhere, it is the potential difference between the two ends of resistor \$R_X\$. We may know absolute potentials \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$ at the ends of the chain, but we don't yet know what the absolute potentials are at any of the junctions between the resistors, so that's our next objective. This diagram should give you some insight about this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVMTBA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In what amounts to an application of Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL), we can traverse the chain of resistors from bottom to top, starting at node B with potential \$V_B\$. As you cross each resistor to the next node, you encounter a rise in potential (assuming, of course, that \$V_A > V_B\$), a rise which is equal to the potential difference across the resistor you just jumped over.

So as you journey upwards from node B to node A, visiting Q and P on the way, the four *absolute* potentials you encounter are:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_B &= -20V\\ \\
V_Q &= V_B + V_{R3} = -4V \\ \\
V_P &= V_Q + V_{R2} = V_B + V_{R3} + V_{R2} = +4V \\ \\
V_A &= V_P + V_{R1} = V_B + V_{R3} + V_{R2} + V_{R1} = +8V\\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You can go the other way if you want, from top to bottom, and the values you get are the same, because of KVL.

Notice how the ratios \$ V_{R1}:V_{R2}:V_{R3}\$ equal the ratios \$R_1:R_2:R_3\$, in conformance with my point (1) above. Notice also that the sum of the individual voltages across each resistor \$V_{R1}+V_{R2}+V_{R3}\$ is equal to the total voltage across the entire chain \$V_A - V_B\$, in accordance with Kirchoff's Voltage Law, as I stated in point (2) above.

Lastly, we can make a general formula for calculating the potential at any node in the chain, by representing the above procedure algebraically. Using \$V_B\$ as the starting point (going *up* the chain from B to A, in other words), and letting \$R_X\$ be some arbitrary resistor in the chain of N resistors, the potential at the top of the Xth resistor \$R_X\$ is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X &= V_B + (V_A - V_B)\frac{R_N+R_{N-1}+\cdots +R_X}{R_1+R_2+\cdots +R_N} \\ \\
&= V_B + (V_A - V_B)\frac{R_N+R_{N-1}+\cdots +R_X}{R_T}
\end{aligned}
$$

Or, the same thing but in the other direction, from A to B, the potential at the bottom of resistor \$R_X\$ is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X &= V_A - (V_A - V_B)\frac{R_1+R_{2}+\cdots +R_X}{R_T}
\end{aligned}
$$

##### Ratios

The above equations might be useful when you know very little about the resistors and voltages, but it's never easy that way. You can often make use of point(1) to derive equations from the ratios of voltages and resistances. Point (1) boils down to this:

$$ R_1:R_2:\cdots :R_N = V_{R1}:V_{R2}:\cdots V_{RN} $$

That means you can form equations like:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{R_1}{R_2} &= \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{R2}} \\ \\
\frac{R_X}{R_Y} &= \frac{V_{RX}}{V_{RY}} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

This would usually be your first approach, because these simple quotients are so much easier to deal with than those other complicated general equations. I'll illustrate this in the context of your actual question, in the last part of this answer.

#### Your Particular Case

You have this arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX0ACB.png)</sup>

Obviously R2 here is actually a 10kΩ potentiometer in your case, but the only thing we need to consider is that the top end of that 10kΩ resistance is to be at +1V potential, and the bottom end will be -1V. The wiper of the potentiometer shall "tap off" some potential between those extremes.

Our task is to find R1 and R3, two unknowns, to achieve the potentials in this schematic, which is a matter of finding two independent simultaneous equations to solve.

##### The hard way

Using the general formulae I derived above, I can make an algrebraic statement about the potential at the bottom of R1:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_P &= V_A - V_T \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} \\ \\
+1 &= 15 - 30\frac{R_1}{R_1 + 10k + R_3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now the potential at the top of R3:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_Q &= V_B + V_T \frac{R_3}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} \\ \\
-1 &= -15V + 30\frac{R_3}{R_1 + 10k + R_3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now you have two simultaneous equations, and two unknowns, so you could solve for R1 and R3. However, your circuit has nice symmetry about it. R1 and R3 both have the same voltage across them, and due to point (1) (voltages are developed in proportion to resistance), we can make the totally awesome simplification:

$$ R_1 = R_3 = R $$

So now we only need one equation (let's use the first one) with \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ replaced by \$R\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
+1 &= 15 - 30\frac{R}{R + 10k + R} \\ \\
&= 15 - 30\frac{R}{2R + 10k} \\ \\
14 &= 30\frac{R}{2R + 10k} \\ \\
14(2R + 10k) &= 30R \\ \\
30R-28R &= 140k \\ \\
2R &= 140k \\ \\
R &= 70k
\end{aligned}
$$

#### The easy way

Returning to my point (1):

1. Each resistor will develop a voltage across it in proportion to its resistance.

In your case, because you already know what voltages you need across all three resistors, you can take advantage of point (1), and build equations out of ratios:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1:R_2 &= V_{R1}:V_{R2} \\ \\
\frac{R_1}{R_2} &= \frac{V_{R1}}{V_{R2}} \\ \\
R_1 &= \frac{R_2V_{R1}}{V_{R2}} \\ \\
&= \frac{10k\Omega \times 14V}{2V} \\ \\
&= 70k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Much easier, right? You'll get better, with experience, at spotting these little relationships regarding potential dividers, and be able in many cases to do the arithmetic in your head even.

Answer (score 0):

R1, the pot, and R2 form a voltage divider. The trick to solving these is to find the total current, and use it and derive the necessary voltage drops across each element.

Let’s start with the pot. You know that your pot is 10k, and you know that each end of the pot will want to be +1 and -1V. That is, it has a voltage drop of 2V. What is the necessary current?

- I(pot) = 2V / 10k = 0.2mA

Since R1, the pot, and R2 are all in series, **all their currents are the same.** We also can figure that R1 = R2, since we want either end of the pot to be symmetrical with ground. And we also know the total voltage across the voltage divider is 30V.

We can then compute the resistances needed to get the right current through the pot, and for the combined IR drops to add up to 30V.

We have:

- R1 = R2 (by symmetry)

And voltage drop for each:

- V(R1) = 30V - (2V + 14V) = 14V
- V(R2) = V(R1)

So for R1 and R2, we need voltage drops of 14V each. Find resistance as follows:

- R1 = R2 = 14V / 0.2mA

Which works out to be **70k ohms** for R1 and R2.

Working backwards using 0.2mA current, you will see that all the voltage drops add up to 30V, with the voltage drop in R1 and R2 being 14V each, and the pot being 2V.

Now, you have a discrepancy in your drawing vs. your text. If in fact you need Vim to go from -1 to +2V, you’ll need to recompute the total current for a 3V drop across the pot, and re-solve for R1 and R2 separately. So let’s do that.

- I(pot) = I(R1) = I(R2) = 3V / 10k = 0.3mA

We need a 13V drop for R1:

- R1 = 13V / 0.3mA = **43.33k**

And 14V for R2:

- R2 = 14V / 0.3mA = **46.66k**

Answer (score 0):

The range of the potentiometer is -1V to +1V, so 2V total. We can use Ohm's law to find the current through the pot: I = V/R = 2/10k = 0.0002A.

The voltage across R1 is 15V - 1V = 14V. Observing that the same current flows through R1, the pot, and R2, we can use Ohm's law again: R = V/I = 14/0.0002 = 70k. Find R2 in the same way, or observe that by symmetry it must by 70k too.

Answer (score 0):

(30V-2V)/2=14V    drop for each resistor

@10k -> 2V drop (pot)

14V is 7 times more than 2V -> 10k*7 = 70k

70000 Ohms. Thats it